# Access individual elements in a list

Tags: grails

I have a list of, let's say, persons. Every person has a field that is "friend", that could be "yes" or "no". Their "friendship" status is presented in a column in the list:

```
<g:if test="${person.friend.status=='no' }">
<td><g:textField name="status" value="${person.friend.status}" readonly="readonly" style="width:60px;border:0px; background:transparent;color:black"/></td>

        <td style="width:20px">
<g:actionSubmitImage action="acceptFriend" value="aceptar"  src="${resource(dir: 'images', file: '/skin/tick_16.png')}" style="width:5px;height:8px;"/>
       </td>
       <td>
        <g:actionSubmitImage action="refuseFriend" value="aceptar"  src="${resource(dir: 'images', file: '/skin/wrong_16.png')}" style="width:5px;height:8px;"/>    
        </td>       
        </g:if>
```

As you can see, when the friend status is "no", two buttons are presented, one to say "that person is my friend" and another one to say "this person is not my friend". My question is:

When i click on the image that says "this person is my friend", I call the action "acceptFriend". But, how to access to the indivivual person instance, to change his status to "yes", and persist in the database? I think it may be with the "params" variable, but how to store it in the params to be accessed in the Controller?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, you cannot use the g:actionSubmitImage like this, because in the tag's documentation is written:

*You cannot use multiple actionSubmitImage tags within the same form and have it work in Internet Explorer 6 or 7 unless you add some custom JavaScript. See this page for a bit more information and a workaround*.

The correct solution would be to have a form per friend in list and then you can easily pass the ID of the domain class.

Comment: Attention, it is not only about IE 6 & 7, but important is, you cannot have more than 1 g:actionSubmitImage in 1 form. So unfortunately it is useless for your use case.

Comment: You were the first one, you get the accept. But, i must say, i CAN use two <g:actionSubmitImage> in the same form, and they work. My mistake was, the field in params was named in a different way that i thought. But both actionSubmitImage work perfectly...

Comment: This look very strange, because it is directly against the documentation. Would it be possible to post the HTML code snipet? Thanks a lot, very curious ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The `actionSubmitImage` creates a submit button in some form.

Create the form for each `person` in the list you're iterating.

In that form, add a hidden field named "id" with a value="${person.id}", and in `acceptFriend` action read it from `params.id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="${createLink(action: 'refuseFriend', id: person.id)}"><img src="${resource(dir: 'images', file: '/skin/wrong_16.png')}" style="width:5px;height:8px;" /></a>
```

This is not tested code, just to give you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

By request of Tom Metz, i post the snippet with both g:actionSubmitImage tags working:

```
<form>
        <g:hiddenField name="contrato" value="${factura.id}"/>
<td>    <g:link title="${message(code :'contratosVer.tooltip')}" controller="campaign" action="show" id="${factura.id}" style="width:160px"> <g:img dir="images" file="/skin/eye_16.png"/></g:link> </td>

        <td><g:textField name="campaign" value="${factura.nombre}" readonly="readonly" style="width:120px;border:0px; background:transparent;color:black"/></td>

        <td><g:textField name="total" value="${factura.presupuestosPendientes.total}" readonly="readonly" style="width:40px;border:0px; background:transparent;color:black"/></td>
            <g:if test="${factura.estado=='Espera'}">

                        <td><g:textField name="estado" value="${factura.estado}" readonly="readonly" style="width:60px;border:0px; background:transparent;color:black"/></td>


        <td style="width:20px">
        <g:actionSubmitImage action="aceptarCamp" value="aceptar"  src="${resource(dir: 'images', file: '/skin/tick_16.png')}" style="width:5px;height:8px;"/>
       </td>
       <td>
        <g:actionSubmitImage action="rechazarCamp" value="aceptar"  src="${resource(dir: 'images', file: '/skin/wrong_16.png')}" style="width:5px;height:8px;"/>    
        </td>       
        </g:if>
            <g:else>

                        <td><g:textField name="estado" value="${factura.estado}" readonly="readonly" style="width:65px;border:0px; background:transparent;color:black"/></td>

                        <td></td><td></td>
            </g:else>
        <g:set var="desc" value="${result.toString()}" />
        <g:if test="${desc.size() > 120}"><g:set var="desc" value="${desc[0..120] + '...'}" /></g:if>
                        </form>
```

Sorry for the delay, mate, but I was away from work for three days.